# How to replace property value with regular expression

Tags: java, regex, maven

In my pom.xml I have the following property:

```
  <properties>
    <targetJar>${app.targetPath}/${app.targetName}-${app.version}.jar</targetJar>
  </properties>
```

But really I don't know `${app.version}`! It may change in the future. Today it looks like: `app-2.0.0.jar`. Tomorrow it may be `app-2.3.1.jar`.

And I must allow it.
What are possible solutions?

Comment: you are asking.. what do you need to set for app.targetPath or.. how to set it?

Comment: app.targetPath is static. Just app.version can be change. Only one jar stored with mask "app-*.jar" in app.targerpath.

Comment: Why do you want to use a regular expression for this???

Comment: So I should know how to load jar with floating name.

Comment: I think you are using the properties wrong. You need to define your property like
<app.version>2.3.1</app.version>

then you can refer ${app.version} at other places

Comment: @DaveNewton what are the alternatives?

Comment: @dhamibirendra it is obviously.

Comment: http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/

Comment: if `${app.targetPath}` == `target/`, `${app.targetName}` == `${project.artifactId}` and `${app.version}` == `${project.version}`, then it's already the default behavior of the maven-jar-plugin. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Your pom.xml has a `<properties>` element that looks similar to this and is often located at the beginning of the file:

```
<properties>
    <maven.test.failure.ignore>true</maven.test.failure.ignore>
    <spring.framework.version>3.0.6.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
    <spring.batch.version>2.1.7.RELEASE</spring.batch.version>
</properties>
```

Within that element your version numbers are defined! They will **not change by itself**!

Comment: Good :) What are alternatives for this case?

Comment: Hm, maybe just to write simple ant taskdef to find this jar and set specific properties? :)